# How to sync contacts and calendar with Linux system, without using Gmail?

Tags: contacts, sync, calendar, linux, privacy

How can I sync my contacts and calendar with a Linux system?

I'd prefer to sync with my desktop, but setting up a server on the internet would also be possible.

I want to avoid Google mail for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you are managing your contacts and calendar on your Linux system.

If you are using Evolution, Sunbird, Thunderbird, Lightening, Kontact or Yahoo then [**MemoToo**](http://memotoo.com/) will get the job done.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Funambol](https://my.funambol.com) (which I think MemoToo is built on). See also:

- [How do I sync calendars using Funambol?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10017/why-does-funambol-sync-only-allow-me-to-sync-contacts) (There's a fix)
- [How to sync calendar with android without google?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10085/how-to-sync-calendar-with-android-without-google)
- [Suggestions for syncing data to someone besides Google? Funambol?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7774/suggestions-for-syncing-data-to-someone-besides-google-funambol)