# How to sync an Android phone with anything other than Google?

Tags: sync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggestions for syncing data to someone besides Google? Funambol?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7774/suggestions-for-syncing-data-to-someone-besides-google-funambol)

As I understand, the Android phone can only sync with Google (GMail, Google Calendar, etc.) out of the box. I can imagine corporate users having a problem with their data residing on Google's servers — despite their "do no evil" credo.

Is there any Android application that lets you sync with the desktop (either Linux or Windows) or corporate server applications (think Exchange)?

Comment: How is this a duplicate, if it was asked 2 years before the question it's marked as a duplicate of?

Answer (score 8):

Finally, I can Sync Android contacts & calendar plus notes & tasks on other platforms...

I've tried all sorts of ways to sync my rooted Android HD2 with Outlook but nothing seems to work, not even HTC's Android sync works particularly well, and it's complicated by the fact that I have other devices (Nokia etc) that I also want to sync and often the software clashes or records get deleted or duplicated....

And then I stumbled across Funambol (http://www.funambol.org) which is a free server that runs on Linux (in my case) and I think there might be a windows version too.  I think there is also a hosted version (http://www.funambol.com) if you don't want to go to the trouble of hosting your own server, but I don't have any experience of that.

So I downloaded the funambol server binary, ran it on a CentOS system and that was pretty much it!  I then downloaded the android client from market place and the symbian client (for my Nokia) from the Ovi store and grabbed the Windows Outlook client.

The installation of these clients was straightforward and now all 3 systems (PC Outlook, HTC HD2 on Android, Nokia on Symbian) all sync up against Funambol with no problems and the phones sync over the air!  And yes, there's a client for iPhones too.

This has really been a life saver for me so I hope others out there discover it and find it as useful! It's a shame it doesn't yet support notes and tasks on Android but hopefully that will come and in any case I sync tasks using Toodledo and GotToDo so no biggie.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, finally i can break free from google calendar!

Answer (score 7):

1. [Root the phone](http://lifehacker.com/5339901/get-root-access-in-android-with-one-click)
2. Flash [CyanogenMod firmware](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=537204) on it
3. Go to the "Work Email" app, put in your Exchange Activesync credentials, Bob's your uncle.

The "Work Email" app is by HTC, the device manufacturers, and I believe has been nicked from the firmware of another Android device. Unfortunately that .apk doesn't install on "standard" G1s.

If rooting/flashing isn't an option for you, then use an IMAP client, plenty available free in the Market. (With the Work Email app you get Exchange global address list integration, which is just fab)

Comment: Ok for the email, but what about contacts, calendars and sms?

Answer (score 5):

Mark/Space is coming out with a software that will directly sync with your desktop:

http://www.markspace.com/products/android/missing-sync-android.html

Answer (score 3):

You are wrong! Android itself does not sync with Google - the G1 and Magic contain Google proprietary software that syncs with Google. If you wanted to sync with something else, the API is there for you to program it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

To not lose your contacts when disabling sync or deleting from Gmail, select "Phone" for Contact type when adding a new contact.  This contact will not be synced with Google.

Answer (score 2):

Telling us which phone you have would help quite a bit, I think.

That being said, I use the out-of-the-box functions with GMail and they do the job perfectly. If you don't trust Google, don't put any sensitive material on your phone. After all, phones might just get lost and then your data is gone as well. I'd rather put my money on Google than putting it on me not losing my phone, ever.

If you'd have a HTC phone, HTC Sync does the job for windows machines just fine. Not entirely sure if there's a Linux or Mac version for the software.

HTC also let you sync with Exchange, I've used it for a couple of days and it worked great, but then we started working on our OCS implementation and it broke - haven't had time to fix it.

**One last piece of software you might want to check though:**
NitroDesk TouchDown: http://www.nitrodesk.com/ 
I've only briefly installed it so no experiences to share, but I've read and heard good things.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

How about also synching gMail, contacts and calendar with Thunderbird, this way even if your Google gets lost for some reason, it will stay in TB local cache. gMail can be synched with TB by either POP3 or IMAP (yes, TB can cache IMPA). You also have TB extensions to synch with gMail Contacts and Google Calendar.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to sync my contacts and all my personal informations to gmail. I’ve been looking for software that can sync my Droid with the Outlook Calendar and Contacts for a while now. I recently stumbled on android-sync. It seems to be the only software that really works for my Droid to directly sync Outlook 2007 via the USB. For more information: http://www.android-sync.com/

Answer (score 2):

Down load JEYO Mobile Companion, Attach phone, select export from file menu, select option, select Symbian vcard format, select destination.

Copy all and save in SD card, goto contacts select vcard, select import from menu, select import from sd card.

thats all.