# Sync to my own server for contacts, sms and notes?

Tags: contacts, sms, sync, notes, to-do-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggestions for syncing data to someone besides Google? Funambol?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7774/suggestions-for-syncing-data-to-someone-besides-google-funambol)

Does anyone know any effort on Android which can sync contacts, sms or even notes/todos to my own server? I saw similar function on Samsung GS3 "Add account" settings page but not sure how it works.

All advice are appreciated. Preferably open source projects. Thanks!

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8824/how-to-sync-an-android-phone-with-anything-other-than-google ; http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2863/how-to-sync-contacts-and-calendar-with-linux-system-without-using-gmail ; http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8928/is-there-a-google-less-personal-cloud-for-contacts-calendar-tasks-and-images

Comment: thanks guys, but not likely they sync SMS or notes.

Answer (score 3):

The most complete solution for private contacts and calendar sync seems to be installing the [CalDAV-Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.caldav.lib) and [CardDAV-Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.carddav.Sync) apps on your phone and setting up a CalDAV / CardDAV server.  Several open-source solutions are available; check the list on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV). I've been a happy user of a DAViCal installation.

Comment: ok that's very cool. Thanks a lot. Do you know any similar standards for SMS and notes?

Comment: No, I don't, unfortunately.