# Has anyone been able to setup a home server as a replacement for Google Sync?

Tags: sync, google-account, active-sync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggestions for syncing data to someone besides Google? Funambol?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7774/suggestions-for-syncing-data-to-someone-besides-google-funambol)
>   [Sync to my own server for contacts, sms and notes?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29199/sync-to-my-own-server-for-contacts-sms-and-notes)

Has anyone been able to setup a home server as a replacement for Google Sync?

I've found a handful of people touching on the right idea, Funambol is one but requires giving your data to another provider. I'd like, to be responsible for my own data.