# Is there a Google-less "personal cloud" for contacts, calendar, tasks and images sync?

Tags: contacts, sync, calendar, cloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggestions for syncing data to someone besides Google? Funambol?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7774/suggestions-for-syncing-data-to-someone-besides-google-funambol)

The idea is to cut Google's (or other 3rd-party) proprietary bits out of an Android installation, while retaining the benefits of "cloud" computing.  For most things there are open-source alternatives: [SK](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/) for keyboard, [K-9 Mail](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/) for e-mail, etc.  However, for the core "cloud" services like Contacts and Calendar, all replacements that I've seen simply redirect you to their own closed and proprietary cloud servers.

From a quick search around the web, the closest open-source alternative is [Funambol](http://funambol.com/)'s client/server solution.  I was wondering if anyone's had any luck setting up their own instance of a "personal cloud" of sorts using this or a similar package, and successfully using it to sync contacts data to an Android device.

Bonus points if there is a package for use with a Synology NAS drive :)

Comment: There's a similar question about this already, but it didn't really get resolved (currently has one answer): [Suggestions for syncing data to someone besides Google? Funambol?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7774/suggestions-for-syncing-data-to-someone-besides-google-funambol)

Comment: How did I miss that?!