# How do I sync calendars using Funambol?

Tags: sync, calendar

I have set up a local Funambol server and created an account. Then I installed Funambol Sync 9.0.1 on my android device (HTC Desire, CyanogenMod 7.0.3 stable (Android 2.3.3)) directly (by APK) because I don't have (and don't want) The Google App Pack.

I configured it and it syncs contacts fine. However, it *only* gives me the option to sync contacts: my user interface looks different than the screenshots on [here](https://android-client.forge.funambol.org/). When opening the sync app I have only one big button that is labeled "Sync Contacts", I don't have a list like in the screenshot. Also, the 'Settings' don't have an "Account" tab.

I wish to sync calendars (at least). What could be the cause of this? Have I installed it incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work now. The problem was that

- calendar sync appearently wasn't supported by Funambol Android client v9.0.1 (which is not the latest version, whatever their download page says)
- the most recent version v10.0.3 has a bug that prevents a calendar from being created if none exists on Android v2.3 and above.

You can either wait for the next snapshot or patch it yourself: in the Funambol Android Client sources in file **src/com/funambol/android/source/pim/calendar/CalendarManager.java** find the line (280):

```
if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) == 8 ) {
```

and replace it with

```
if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 ) {
```

and compile.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the reviews on the [Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.funambol.androidsync), it looks like the ability to sync to your own server was removed in one of the latest versions of Funambol Sync.

Comment: Where did you find that? I read all the comments, and the only comment concerning the calendar sync says that it's available with firmware 2.2.1 and higher. I do however have 2.3.3, so shouldn't it be available?