# How to sync calendar with android without google?

Tags: sync, dropbox, calendar

is there a way to sync an Ubuntu calendar application like Thunderbird Lightning or Evolution with an Android device without using google-calendar?

At the moment I am syncing my Thunderbird-Lightning calendars on different computers via Dropbox, what is much more reliable than google-calendar. Another big advantage over google-calendar is, that I can access my appointments offline as well, since the calendar files are synced onto the harddrive of each computer by Dropbox.

I'd like to access those calendars via my android device as well.

- The Dropbox-app for android does not support automatic syncing yet, so it seems like I have to use another service.
- Apart from that I guess I need to know an android app, that can access a calendar-file stored in ics-format.

Thanks in advance
YSN

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2863/how-to-sync-contacts-and-calendar-with-linux-system-without-using-gmail, but there are more answers here.

Comment: You can also sync Google Calendar with offline applications.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a CalDAV server such as [SOGo](http://sogo.nu/) or [DAViCal](http://www.davical.org/) with Lightning, you can then use [CalDAV-Sync](http://dmfs.org/caldav/) on your Android device to sync your calendars there as well. SOGo also has CardDAV support, and [CardDAV-Sync](http://dmfs.org/carddav/) will keep your contacts in sync as well.

Comment: There are many CardDAV servers but not all pairs of server and client work. You need to check your intended combinations before choosing a server.

Answer (score 2):

DAViCal is a great calendar server, so if your phone supports iCal, you might look at either hosting a local instance on the pc you want to sync with, or hosting it on a server or nas server you may/may not have (i use my nas for this.).

[Yahoo! Calendar](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/calendar/yahoocalendar/sync/) is also great for syncing. I use it to sync with my fiance for our wedding planning :)

Comment: Sounds very promising! I will try t o set it up. But I need to have my calendars available offline as well, what should depend of the client software... The next question would be, whether there is an Android app, that supports iCal...

Answer (score 2):

So I was trying to do this with my Outlook Calendar (at work).

1. Export a ICS file to a Dropbox folder
2. Use DropSync on Android to keep the file in sync on the local sdcard
3. Use [ICSSync](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.nightlabs.android.icssync) to parse the ICS file and add it to the native Calendar app

The above approach works for me, ofcourse you'd have to find a way to schedule/automate the export of your calendar from your Calendering app on Ubuntu. For Outlook, I am using [Outlook2ICal](http://www.ryanwatkins.net/software/outlook2ical.js).

Answer (score 1):

Never tried it myself, but maybe it helps:

> [Funambol](http://www.funambol.com/)  wirelessly syncs contacts, calendars, email and pictures between mobile phones, PCs, tablets and connected devices via the cloud.

They offer a (free) cloud service, or you can install the OS-Version yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately funambol does not work with calendars yet on android, as it seems. Apart from that, I want my calendars available offline - my aim is not to avoid google. Maybe I can try and duplicate my offline calendars to google-calendar and simply sync that. I will open a new question for that.

Comment: As stated in http://www.funambol.com/solutions/android.php: The Funambol Android Client syncs contacts, calendars and pictures on Android phones. And Funambol is a *SYNC* solution - meaning that your data is always available offline, but will be synced when you are online.

Comment: Funambol also appears not to have an Ubuntu client. Or a Thunderbird 3x client.